# C strings and bitwise operators

Tags: c, arrays, bitwise-operators

So I have a input file which contains:

1 2 288815 1 13 60980

1 6 257684 1 8 250730

0 2 468583 0 0 61388

1 6 210352 0 3 23664

0 0 358489 1 13 219326

0 0 9676 0 3 402661

0 3 280447 0 3 288153

1 7 4957 0 0 397725

This information has been read in line by line into an array.

The first and fourth numbers on each line are a valid check, the second and fifth numbers are a tag, and the third and sixth numbers are an address.

I need to create a function which takes three arguments: myArray, index, tag

The function will check the line at the index given in the parameter. It will first check to see if there is a tag in the line which is equal to the tag in the parameter. If it is, then it will check if the valid number is a 1 or a 0. If it is a 1, then it should return the address after the tag. Else, it should return "Page fault".

This is my first stab at it:

```
char *lookUpTLB(char **array, int TLBI, int TLBT)
{
if (array[TLBI][2] == TLBT)// checks if the second number in the array is equal to the tag
{
    //char **ar = array[TLBI] + 2;
    if (array[TLBI][0] == '1')//checks the valid number
    {
        return array[TLBI]+11;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Page Fault";
    }
}
else if (array[TLBI][13] == TLBT)//checks if the 13th index is equal to the tag
{
    if (array[TLBI][11] == '1')//checks the valid number
    {
        return array[TLBI] + 15;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Page Fault";
    }
}
else
{
    return "Page Fault";
}
}
```

There are few problems with this code, but the main idea is there. I can't use indexing like a tried to with my code because not all the numbers are the same length. I've been told I can do this using bitwise operators, but I'm very confused on how to do that.

Here is what I want to happen as an example:

Calling lookUpTLB(myArray, 0, 2); should return 288815

Calling lookUpTLB(myArray, 0, 13); should return 60980

Calling lookUpTLB(myArray, 3, 3); should return page fault because the valid number is 0

Calling lookUpTLB(myArray, 3, 6); should return 210352

I'm pretty new to C, any help on how I should do this function? Let me know if I need to be more clear.

Comment: Since all your values are integers it would make more sense to parse the data first so that you have an array of ints rather than an array of strings.

Comment: If this question has been answered, keep the original visible, so that later visitors to the site can see it.

Answer (score 0):

,It seems that he should be converted to a number simply format the file if not a fixed length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct data {
    char valid;
    int tag;
    int32_t address;
} Data;

typedef struct rec {
    Data data[2];
} Record;

int32_t lookUpTLB(Record *array, int index, int tag);

int main(void){
    Record array[16];
    int n=0;//number of record
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    while(6==fscanf(fp, " %c %d %" SCNd32 " %c %d %" SCNd32 ,
        &array[n].data[0].valid, &array[n].data[0].tag, &array[n].data[0].address,
        &array[n].data[1].valid, &array[n].data[1].tag, &array[n].data[1].address))
    {
        ++n;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    int index, tag;
    int32_t address;
    while(1){
        printf("index(-1.:end) and tag\n");
        if(2!=scanf("%d %d", &index, &tag) || index == -1)
            break;
        if(0>(address = lookUpTLB(array, index, tag)))
            printf("Page fault\n");
        else
            printf("%" PRId32 "\n", address);
    }
    return 0;
}

#define PAGE_FAULT -1

int32_t lookUpTLB(Record *array, int TLBI, int TLBT){
    if(array[TLBI].data[0].tag == TLBT){
        return array[TLBI].data[0].valid == '1' ?
            array[TLBI].data[0].address :
            PAGE_FAULT;
    } else if(array[TLBI].data[1].tag == TLBT){
        return array[TLBI].data[1].valid == '1' ?
            array[TLBI].data[1].address :
            PAGE_FAULT;
    }
    return PAGE_FAULT;
}
```

**DEMO**:

```
index(-1.:end) and tag
0 2
288815
index(-1.:end) and tag
0 13
60980
index(-1.:end) and tag
3 3
Page fault
index(-1.:end) and tag
3 6
210352
index(-1.:end) and tag
-1.
```